Django messaging functionality not working
So I'm trying to add messaging functionality to my e-commerce website, where buyers can message sellers and sellers can message buyers once the buyer has purchased something from them (haven't written the code for that yet, just want basic messaging functionality out of the way). So this is what I've tried.
So about my views, I have two views. Through the message_seller view I can directly message that specific seller, it takes me to the inbox of that seller, and the user_messages_view is like an inbox of that user's messages, sent and received, and the user can click on a selected message to open up the conversation.
I can send message to other users, but there is one problem with this. That is when a user receives a message initiated by another user, the inbox shows an incorrect self-conversation rather than the actual message. Even though the unread message counter correctly shows the unread messages for that user.
Screenshots:

I have sent the business H&M a new message right now

Now when I log in as the user with the H&M business, I see this, as I was saying the unread message counter is right, I have 1 unread message, but why is it a conversation with me?
Can anyone please help me solve the issue? Thanks in advance!
My models.py:
class Business(models.Model):
    BUSINESS_TYPE_CHOICES = [
        ('product', 'Product Business'),
        ('service', 'Service Business'),
    ]
    seller = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='business')
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
    business_slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, blank=True)
    business_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=BUSINESS_TYPE_CHOICES)
    countries = models.ManyToManyField(Country)
    states = models.ManyToManyField(State)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True, null=True)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='business_profiles/', blank=True, null=True)
    banner_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='business_banners/', blank=True, null=True)
    is_featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.business_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.business_slug:
            self.business_slug = slugify(self.business_name)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class Message(models.Model):
    sender = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name='sent_messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    recipient = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, related_name='received_messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business, related_name='messages', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    content = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return f'Message from {self.sender} to {self.recipient} in {self.business}'


My views.py:
@login_required
def message_seller(request, business_slug):
    business = get_object_or_404(Business, business_slug=business_slug)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        if content:
            Message.objects.create(
                sender=request.user,
                recipient=business.seller,
                business=business,
                content=content
            )
            return redirect('message_seller', business_slug=business.business_slug)

    # Mark messages as read for the current user and business
    Message.objects.filter(recipient=request.user, business=business).update(is_read=True)

    messages = Message.objects.filter(
        Q(sender=request.user, recipient=business.seller) |
        Q(sender=business.seller, recipient=request.user)
    ).filter(business=business).order_by('timestamp')

    individual_business_message_counter = Message.objects.filter(recipient=request.user, business=business, is_read=False).count()
    context = {
        'business': business,
        'messages': messages,
        'individual_business_message_counter': individual_business_message_counter,
    }
    return render(request, 'business/message.html', context)


@login_required
def user_messages_view(request, business_slug=None):
    # Fetch all businesses the user has interacted with
    businesses = Business.objects.filter(
        Q(messages__sender=request.user) | Q(messages__recipient=request.user)
    ).distinct()

    user_messages = []
    unread_businesses = set()

    for business in businesses:
        last_message = Message.objects.filter(
            Q(sender=request.user, recipient=business.seller) |
            Q(sender=business.seller, recipient=request.user)
        ).filter(business=business).order_by('-timestamp').first()

        unread_count = Message.objects.filter(recipient=request.user, business=business, is_read=False).count()
        if unread_count > 0:
            unread_businesses.add(business)

        user_messages.append({
            'business': business,
            'last_message': last_message,
            'unread_count': unread_count,
        })

    unread_message_counter = len(unread_businesses)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        business_slug = request.POST.get('business_slug')
        business = get_object_or_404(Business, business_slug=business_slug)
        content = request.POST.get('content')
        if content:
            Message.objects.create(
                sender=request.user,
                recipient=business.seller,
                business=business,
                content=content
            )
        return redirect(f'{request.path}?business_slug={business.business_slug}')

    selected_business = None
    messages = []
    business_slug = request.GET.get('business_slug')
    if business_slug:
        selected_business = get_object_or_404(Business, business_slug=business_slug)
        messages = Message.objects.filter(
            Q(sender=request.user, recipient=selected_business.seller, business=selected_business) |
            Q(sender=selected_business.seller, recipient=request.user, business=selected_business)
        ).order_by('timestamp')

        Message.objects.filter(recipient=request.user, business=selected_business).update(is_read=True)

    context = {
        'user_messages': user_messages,
        'selected_business': selected_business,
        'messages': messages,
        'unread_message_counter': unread_message_counter,
    }
    return render(request, 'business/user_messages.html', context)

My urls.py:
urlpatterns = [
    path('message/<slug:business_slug>/', views.message_seller, name='message_seller'),
    path('messages/', views.user_messages_view, name='user_messages'),
    path('messages/<slug:business_slug>/', views.user_messages_view, name='user_messages_with_slug'),
]

My message.html:
<main class="content">
    <div class="container p-0">

        <h1 class="h3 mb-3 mt-3">Messages</h1>

        <div class="card">
            <div class="row g-0">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-5 col-xl-3 border-right">

                    {% for message in user_messages %}
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0">
                        <div class="badge bg-success float-right">{{ individual_business_message_counter }}</div>
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
                            <img src="{{ message.business.profile_picture.url }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" width="40px" height="40px">
                            <div class="flex-grow-1 ml-3">
                                {{ message.business.business_name }}

                                {% if message.last_message %}
                                    {% if not message.last_message.is_read %}
                                        <div class="small">{{ message.last_message.content }}</div>
                                    {% else %}
                                        <div class="small"><b>{{ message.last_message.content }}</b></div>
                                    {% endif %}
                                {% else %}
                                    <p>No messages yet.</p>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    {% endfor %}

                    <hr class="d-block d-lg-none mt-1 mb-0">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-7 col-xl-9">
                    <div class="py-2 px-4 border-bottom d-none d-lg-block">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center py-1">
                            <div class="position-relative">
                                <img src="{{ business.profile_picture.url }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="Sharon Lessman" width="40" height="40">
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex-grow-1 pl-3">
                                <strong>{{ business.business_name }}</strong>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="position-relative">
                        <div class="chat-messages p-4">

                            {% for message in messages %}
                                {% if message.sender == request.user %}
                                    <div class="chat-message-right pb-4">
                                        <div>
                                            <img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="Chris Wood" width="40" height="40">
                                            <div class="text-muted small text-nowrap mt-2">{{ message.timestamp }}</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="flex-shrink-1 bg-light rounded py-2 px-3 mr-3">
                                            <div class="font-weight-bold mb-1">You</div>
                                            {{ message.content }}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                {% else %}
                                    <div class="chat-message-left pb-4">
                                        <div>
                                            <img src="{{ business.banner_image.url }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="{{ business.business_name }}" width="40" height="40">
                                            <div class="text-muted small text-nowrap mt-2">{{ message.timestamp }}</div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="flex-shrink-1 bg-light rounded py-2 px-3 ml-3">
                                            <div class="font-weight-bold mb-1">{{ business.business_name }}</div>
                                            {{ message.content }}
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                {% endif %}
                            {% endfor %}

                        </div>
                    </div>

                    {% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
                        <form method="post">
                            {% csrf_token %}
                            <div class="flex-grow-0 py-3 px-4 border-top">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <input name="content" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your message">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    {% endif %}

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>

My user_messages.html:
<main class="content mt-5 mb-5">
    <div class="container p-0">
        <h1 class="h3 mb-3">Your Messages</h1>
        <div class="card">
            <div class="row g-0">
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-5 col-xl-3 border-right">
                    {% for user_message in user_messages %}
                    <a href="{% url 'user_messages' %}?business_slug={{ user_message.business.business_slug }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0">
                        <div class="badge bg-success float-right">{{ user_message.unread_count }}</div>
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
                            <img src="{{ user_message.business.profile_picture.url }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" width="40px" height="40px">
                            <div class="flex-grow-1 ml-3">
                                {{ user_message.business.business_name }}
                                {% if user_message.last_message %}
                                <div class="small">{{ user_message.last_message.content }}</div>
                                {% else %}
                                <p>No messages yet.</p>
                                {% endif %}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    {% endfor %}
                    <hr class="d-block d-lg-none mt-1 mb-0">
                </div>
                <div class="col-12 col-lg-7 col-xl-9">
                    {% if selected_business %}
                    <div class="py-2 px-4 border-bottom d-none d-lg-block">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center py-1">
                            <div class="position-relative">
                                <img src="{{ selected_business.profile_picture.url }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="{{ selected_business.business_name }}" width="40" height="40">
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex-grow-1 pl-3">
                                <strong>{{ selected_business.business_name }}</strong>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% endif %}
                    <div class="position-relative">
                        <div class="chat-messages p-4">
                            {% for message in messages %}
                            {% if message.sender == request.user %}
                            <div class="chat-message-right pb-4">
                                <div>
                                    <img src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/avatar/avatar1.png" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="User Avatar" width="40" height="40">
                                    <div class="text-muted small text-nowrap mt-2">{{ message.timestamp }}</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex-shrink-1 bg-light rounded py-2 px-3 mr-3">
                                    <div class="font-weight-bold mb-1">You</div>
                                    {{ message.content }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% else %}
                            <div class="chat-message-left pb-4">
                                <div>
                                    <img src="{{ selected_business.profile_picture.url }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="{{ selected_business.business_name }}" width="40" height="40">
                                    <div class="text-muted small text-nowrap mt-2">{{ message.timestamp }}</div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="flex-shrink-1 bg-light rounded py-2 px-3 ml-3">
                                    <div class="font-weight-bold mb-1">{{ selected_business.business_name }}</div>
                                    {{ message.content }}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            {% endif %}
                            {% empty %}
                            <p>No messages yet.</p>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    {% if request.user.is_authenticated and selected_business %}
                    <form method="post" action="{% url 'user_messages' %}?business_slug={{ selected_business.business_slug }}">
                        {% csrf_token %}
                        <input type="hidden" name="business_slug" value="{{ selected_business.business_slug }}">
                        <div class="flex-grow-0 py-3 px-4 border-top">
                            <div class="input-group">
                                <input name="content" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type your message">
                                <button class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>


you can find my code here
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1XYUKv_sZmVT6XSaadmRXtZpUX030mPPh?usp=drive_link
You can take a look for yourself what I mean when I say that when conversations are initiated by a user to a business, the business receives that convo as a self inbox to himself, which is very weird.
But I've only got 19 hours to award the correct answer with 50 points, so we have to be quick!
Thanks!

The problem is basically is that when a user messages a business owner, the business owner isn't receiving the message.

Yes but what I mean is that, the message isn't showing up on the recipient's inbox.

Your query is only for messages sent to and received from businesses, not for messages received for a business. It is unclear how such chats with each sender are supposed to be displayed, since chat messages are grouped by business.

I really have no idea what a corner I have pushed myself into with trying to achieve this functionality, but you're one of the smartest people I know and I am not giving up yet because I really still want to achieve it. What I essentially want is users to be able to send messages to business owners through both message_seller and user_messages views, and business owners being able to receive them. Also write another view in the future message_buyer where business owners can message a buyer and buyers can receive them. If you had to update my code given my models, how would you do it?

I added an answer. Next time, please define how such chats are supposed to be displayed, and show the queries that you tried but are facing problems with. Stack Overflow is not a free coding service.


when a user messages a business owner, the business owner isn't receiving the message.


what I mean is that, the message isn't showing up on the recipient's inbox.

Your query is only for messages sent to and received from businesses, not for messages received for a business. The question does not define how such chats with each sender are supposed to be displayed, since chat messages are grouped by business in the question.
Nevertheless, this answer will demonstrate how to query for and display messages for a business with other users. Similarly, you will need to handle if request.user == business.seller for the case where "business owners can message a buyer" in if request.method == 'POST', which is not shown in this answer.

1.a. Query user_messages for business with other users, pass 'user' to template:
def user_messages_view(request):
    businesses = Business.objects.filter(
        Q(messages__sender=request.user) | Q(messages__recipient=request.user)
    ).distinct()
    user_messages = []

    for business in businesses:
        if request.user == business.seller:
            # Query user_messages for business with other users
            messages = Message.objects.filter(
                Q(sender=business.seller) |
                Q(recipient=business.seller)
            ).filter(business=business).order_by('-timestamp')
            for user, chat in itertools.groupby(messages, lambda m: m.recipient if m.sender == request.user else m.sender):
                last_message = next(chat)
                user_messages.append({
                    'business': business,
                    'last_message': last_message,
                    'user': user,
                })
        else:
            last_message = Message.objects.filter(
                Q(sender=request.user, recipient=business.seller) |
                Q(sender=business.seller, recipient=request.user)
            ).filter(business=business).order_by('-timestamp').first()
            unread_businesses = set()
            if Message.objects.filter(recipient=request.user, business=business, is_read=False).exists():
                unread_businesses.add(business)
            user_messages.append({
                'business': business,
                'last_message': last_message,
                'unread_count': len(unread_businesses),
            })

    ...

1.b. Handle display user_messages for business with other users, using message.user:
{% for message in user_messages %}
    {% if message.user %}
    {# Handle display user_messages for business with other users #}
    <a href="{% url 'user_messages' %}?business_slug={{ message.business.business_slug }}&username={{ message.user.username }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0">
        <div class="badge bg-success float-right">{{ individual_business_message_counter }}</div>
        <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
            <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name={{ message.user.username }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" width="40px" height="40px">
            <div class="flex-grow-1 ml-3">
                {{ message.user.username }}
                {% if message.last_message %}
                <div class="small">{{ message.last_message.content }}</div>
                {% else %}
                <p>No messages yet.</p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    {% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'user_messages' %}?business_slug={{ message.business.business_slug }}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action border-0">
        <div class="badge bg-success float-right">{{ individual_business_message_counter }}</div>
        <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
            <img src="{{ message.business.profile_picture.url }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" width="40px" height="40px">
            <div class="flex-grow-1 ml-3">
                {{ message.business.business_name }}
                {% if message.last_message %}
                <div class="small">{{ message.last_message.content }}</div>
                {% else %}
                <p>No messages yet.</p>
                {% endif %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

2.a. Query messages for selected_business with selected_user, using username:
def user_messages_view(request):
    ...

    selected_business = None
    messages = []
    if 'business_slug' in request.GET:
        business_slug = request.GET.get('business_slug')
        selected_business = get_object_or_404(Business, business_slug=business_slug)
        if request.user == selected_business.seller and 'username' in request.GET:
            # Query messages for selected_business with selected_user
            username = request.GET.get('username')
            selected_user = get_object_or_404(CustomUser, username=username)
            messages = Message.objects.filter(
                Q(sender= selected_user, recipient=selected_business.seller) |
                Q(sender=selected_business.seller, recipient= selected_user)
            ).filter(business=selected_business).order_by('timestamp')
        else:
            messages = Message.objects.filter(
                Q(sender=request.user, recipient=selected_business.seller) |
                Q(sender=selected_business.seller, recipient=request.user)
            ).filter(business=selected_business).order_by('timestamp')

    ...

2.b. Handle display messages from selected_business:
{% for message in messages %}
{% if message.sender == request.user %}
...
{% elif selected_business.seller == request.user %}
{# Handle display messages from selected_business #}
<div class="chat-message-right pb-4">
    <div>
        <img src="{{ selected_business.banner_image.url }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="{{ selected_business.business_name }}" width="40" height="40">
        <div class="text-muted small text-nowrap mt-2">{{ message.timestamp }}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-shrink-1 bg-light rounded py-2 px-3 mr-3">
        <div class="font-weight-bold mb-1">You</div>
        {{ message.content }}
    </div>
</div>
{% else %}
...
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}

2.c. Handle display selected_user:
{% if selected_business %}
<div class="col-12 col-lg-7 col-xl-9">
    <div class="py-2 px-4 border-bottom d-none d-lg-block">
        <div class="d-flex align-items-center py-1">
            {% if selected_user %}
            {# Handle display selected_user #}
            <div class="position-relative">
                <img src="https://ui-avatars.com/api/?name={{ selected_user.username }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="{{ selected_user.username }}" width="40" height="40">
            </div>
            <div class="flex-grow-1 pl-3">
                <strong>{{ selected_user.username }}</strong>
            </div>
            {% else %}
            <div class="position-relative">
                <img src="{{ selected_business.profile_picture.url }}" class="rounded-circle mr-1" alt="{{ selected_business.business_name }}" width="40" height="40">
            </div>
            <div class="flex-grow-1 pl-3">
                <strong>{{ selected_business.business_name }}</strong>
            </div>
            {% endif %}
        </div>
    </div>


Thank you for the answer, now I can receive messages sent by users, when I reply, instead of the message going to the user, I am just messaging myself somehow.

I am sorry, I apologise for my mistake.

Hey aaron, I wrote the message_buyer view and messaging functionality works now, but a totally different random problem popped up.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78597552/django-messages-showing-up-for-unknown-reasons
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78597495/django-context-processors-code-not-working
I have tried fixing them with different techniques, but just won't work. Sorry to bother you!
